# Formal way of defining a weighted average

Tags: mean, notation

I am looking for a nice and formal way to define moving averages :

$y = \sum_{i=0}^N w_ix_i=<\mathbf{w},\mathbf{x}>$

and  especially the fact that weights have to equal one, i.e.
 $\sum_{i=0}^N w_i=1$.

This property seems quite obvious to me,  as you somehow want the output to have the same "level" as the input values. However, I don't know how to describe it a more mathematical way ..

Can somebody help me out ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I think that pretty much what I was looking for. :)

Comment: ... and the weights $w_i$ are a vector in the [unit simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_ix_i$ is a weighted average of the $x_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i=1$ and each of the $w_i\geq0$, then $y$ is a [convex combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of the $x_i$.